# It is ok to consider that lists used as logical values will not be converted to True/False in Python?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I am studying a program by Peter Norvig, of AI book fame, [found here](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) and he uses this construction:

```
def candidates(word): 
    "Generate possible spelling corrections for word."
    return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])
```

I do understand how it works. For the sake of other readers, I will explain here.

Functions `known`, `edits1` and `edits2` return lists that can be empty.

The code uses the truth value of these lists to find the first that evaluates to `True`. Since Python short circuits the expression, that will be the answer.

But, for this expression to work, it is necessary that the operands are used as the return value, i.e. the lists will be kept as they are received, and not transformed to `True` or `False` while the logical expression is interpreted.

Another way to do that, using walrus, would be:

```
  if a:=known([word]):
    return a
  elif b:=know(edits1(word)): #fixed elsif type on edit
    return b
  elif c:=know(edits2(word)): #fixed elsif type on edit
    return c
  else: 
    return [word]
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the assumption that the value returned will be the original value of the operand, and not its truth value, the expected and correct behavior for any Python interpreter?
2. Is this the Pythonic style?

Comment: Are you confused by the idea of `falsey` and `truthy`?  In python, a non-empty list is `truthy` - it is considered to be affirmative when used in a condition (but it is not converted to the boolean True).  The inverse is true of an empty list - it is considered `falsey` in a condition (but does not get internally converted to False).

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, python allows you to operate on the idea of 'truthiness' of a container.  For built-in containers, this defaults to whether or not they are empty.  So `[]` (an empty list) is *falsey*, but it is not `False`.  You can test these things rather directly:

```
Python 3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27) 
>>> if []: print('Nope!')
... 
>>> if [] == False: print('Nope!')
... 
>>> if [] is False: print('Nope!')
... 
>>> if ['a']: print('Yep!')
... 
Yep!
>>>
```

Comment: I fully understand the truthness value of lists (and other itens).

What am I asking is if:

``` [] or [0,1]```

will always `[0,1]`, disregarding the Python implementation, or it can return `True` in some interpreters.

And, if using this property is Pythonic.

Comment: `[] or [0,1]` will _always_ result in `[0,1]`, yes.  This is idiomatic, understood, and can be relied upon.  If you really, really wanted to be sure (you have some use case that would break if it stopped working for some reason), just put a unit test in place that asserts that `([] or [1]) == [1]`.

Comment: @Xexeo yes very pythonic.  Before Python added the ternary operator `a = b if b else c`, the accepted way to write that was `a = b or c`.  It's not intuitive if you're used to a language that forces boolean expressions to have a true/false value, but still useful and easy to get used to.

Comment: It think `a = b or c` is still a valid idiom. The conditional operator was added to replace chains like `a = b and c or d`, which would assign `d` to `a` if either `b` or `c` was false.

Answer (score 2):

#### "Is the assumption that the value returned will be the original value of the operand, and not its truth value, the expected and correct behavior for any Python interpreter?"

Yes, the returned value will be the "original value". That is, a list is returned. An empty list is considered as falsey when testing a *truth value*. From the python docs for [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) <sub><sup>(emphasis mine)</sup></sub>:

> Here are most of the built-in **objects considered false**:
>
> - constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`.
> - zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
> - empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

Checking of objects' truth value *does not cast the object to boolean*:

```py
In [67]: lst_a, lst_b = [], [1,2,3]
    ...:
    ...: if lst_a: # The [] is falsey
    ...:     print(lst_a)
    ...: if lst_b: # Nonempty list is truthy
    ...:     print(lst_b)
    ...:
[1, 2, 3] # lst_b is still a list.
```

this is also [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) with

> Boolean operations or and and always return **one of their operands**.

#### Is this the Pythonic style?

I would say that yes, for example the following function

```py
def candidates(word):
    if a := known([word]):
        return a
    elif b := know(edits1(word)):
        return b
    elif c := know(edits2(word)):
        return c
    return [word]
```

is "pythonic". It is readable and clear (same as you proposed, with removing the last unnecessary `else` and changing "elsif" to "elif").

Note that the code you linked if from 2007-2016, when there was no walrus operator (`:=`), since it was added in Python 3.8. In library code, the walrus operator will probably be coming later on, since based on the popular numpy package [download stats](https://pypistats.org/packages/numpy), at the time of writing only roughly 7.3% of the users have Python version that supports the walrus operator.

#### Few words about `a or b` vs `a | b`

Note that the [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) works with many data object types (also lists), and returns the *first truthy value*.  This is very different operator from the [Bitwise operator `|`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types). Trying to do `list_a | list_b` will result into `TypeError`, and if you do `bool(list_a) | bool(list_b)`, the outcome will be a boolean.